# Как установить GUI (графический интерфейс) в FreeBSD без интернета прямо с dvd1-установочного файла?

Tags: freebsd

У меня не получилось установить графический интерфейс в FreeBSD без интернета ! Я установил FreeBSD но после перезагрузки компьютера я попадаю в терминал ! Во многих документациях, видео, авторы скачивают и устанавливают графический интерфейс с помощью беспроводного интернета (wifi) но не один из них не устанавливает GUI с установочного файла ! Там в официальном сайте сказано что в файле dvd1:
Содержит все необходимое для установки базовой операционной системы FreeBSD, документации и небольшого набора готовых пакетов, предназначенных для запуска графической рабочей станции.
У меня вопрос: Можно ли установить графический интерфейс прямо из dvd1-файла FreeBSD без интернета? Помогите пожалуйста я долго искал ответ чтоб впервые увидеть FreeBSD на моём компьютере но не нашёл! Может здесь я найду правильный и рабочий ответ на свой вопрос? Заранее спасибо (^_^) !

Answer (score 0):

```
mount -t cd9660 /dev/cd0 /mnt/
ls -l /mnt/packages/FreeBSD:11:amd64/All/
```

Появится куча файлов, это скомпиленный софт. Ставить софт, например, так:

```
pkg install zsh-5.3.1_1.txz
```

Может ругаться на отсутствие зависимостей, ищете софт в этой же папке и ставите.

Answer (score -2):

А лучше, наверно, использовать утилиту bsdconfig - там через GUI в консоли можно выбрать откуда ставить софт.
P.S. вылезает проблема, что при попытке pkg install

```
The package management tool is not yet installed on your system.
Do you want to fetch and install it now? [y/N]
```

и все равно пытается скачать с интернета.
Поэтому гугл подсказал, что можно использовать нечто подобное:

```
env REPOS_DIR=/mnt/packages/repos pkg rquery "%n"
```

или прописать свой репо, пример есть на диске dvd:

```
cat /mnt/packages/repos/FreeBSD_install_cdrom.conf

FreeBSD_install_cdrom: {
url: "file:///dist/packages/${ABI}",
mirror_type: "none",
 enabled: yes
}

FreeBSD: {
enabled: no
}
```